# Store IP Address in database during sign up in laravel 5.1

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.1

Hii i want to store ip addresss in database in laravel 5.1.I have searched in google to store ip address and they suggest me to store ip address like Request::ip(); or other method $request->ip();.when i used this and keep this line as $request->ip(); then it print the ip address.But I have used array $data in auth controller during sign up.

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
           'ip' => $data->ip(),
        ]);
    }
```

the main problem is when i use this line as storing ip like this 'ip' => $data->ip(), it cause error
FatalErrorException in AuthController.php 
Call to a member function ip() on a non-object.The error is in this line 'ip' => $data->ip(). Can you please help me.

Comment: var_dump your `$data`

Comment: Can you explain it more

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`request()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-request) function which returns the current [request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests) instance as:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
       'ip' => request()->ip(),
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the error is that `$data` is an array, not an object. You cant call functions on an object. Maybe this will work:

```
'ip' => $data['ip']
```